# Fractal parseIncludes not working

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

I'm using the Laravel framework for my web app, eloquent models for data and Fractal to transform some data.

I want to use the `parseIncludes` functionality of fractal but I can't seem to get it working despite following the docs.

Here's my code:

**StudentTransformer.php**

```
class StudentTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{

    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'course'
    ];

    public function transform(Student $student)
    {
        return [
            'name'           => $student->name,
            // other attributes
        ];
    }

    public function includeCourse(Student $student)
    {
        $course = $student->course;

        return $this->item($course, new CourseTransformer);
    }

}
```

**CourseTransformer.php**

```
class CourseTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Course $course)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $course->name
            // other attributes
        ];
    }
}
```

In one of my controllers:

```
$student = App\Models\Student::first();

$fractal = new \League\Fractal\Manager();

$fractal->parseIncludes('/student?include=course');

$fractal->setSerializer(new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());

$response = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Item($student, new \App\Transformers\Models\StudentTransformer);

return response()->json($fractal->createData($response)->toArray());
```

Also, when I remove the `availableIncludes` from the StudentTransformer and use `defaultIncludes` instead, like so:

```
protected $defaultIncludes = [
    'course'
];
```

It works just fine?! No idea why! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. For the benefit of others, the issue was here:

```
$fractal->parseIncludes('/student?include=course');
```

It should just be:

```
$fractal->parseIncludes('course');
```